# Is this function a metric?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$,$d$ be a metric space.
Define $d'$ as the minimum of $1$ and $d$:

$$ d':\ X^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ d'(x,y) = \min\{1,d(x,y)\} $$

The question is whether $d'$ is a metric.
I've managed to prove that the first two properties of a metric hold for this function, but I can't seem to figure out how to prove the triangle inequality. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $d(x,y) \ge 0 $ and $d(x,y)+d(y,z) \ge d(x,z) $
giving:
$$d'(x,y)+d'(y,z)$$ $$ =  \min\{1,d(x,y)\} +  \min\{1,d(y,z)\} $$ $$= \min\{1+1,1+d(x,y),d(y,z)+1,d(x,y)+d(y,z)\}$$ $$ \ge \min\{1,d(x,y)+d(y,z)\} $$ $$\ge  \min\{1,d(x,z)\}$$ $$ = d'(x,z)$$

Comment: Did you just prove that the triangle inequality never holds? $d'(x,y) + d'(y,z) \le d'(x,z)$

Comment: @SydKerckhove: indeed my inequalities were backwards, now corrected.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you convince me of the last inequality?

Comment: @SydKerckhove: If $g\ge j$ and $h \ge k$, then $g \ge j \ge\min\{j,k\}$ and    $h \ge k \ge\min\{j,k\}$,  so $ \min\{g,h\} \ge \min\{j,k\}$.  Now let $g=1$, $h=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, $j=1$, $k=d(x,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y,z\in X$; then you have two cases:

1. if $d(x,z)\le 1$, then $d'(x,z)=d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)\le d'(x,y)+d'(y,z)$
2. if $d(x,z)>1$, then $d'(x,z)=1$; since $1<d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$, we must have either that one among $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)$ is at least $1$ (and we're done), or they are both less than $1$ and so $d'(x,y)+d'(y,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z)>d'(x,y)$.

Comment: I don't think your statement 'at least one among $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)$ is greater than $1$' is correct.
Take $d(x,z) = 1.1 > 1$, then $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)$ can be both $0.55$ which is not greater than $1$. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @SydKerckhove No, you aren't. Now it should be fixed.