# For a metric space X, with metric d. is m(p,q)=min{1, d(p,q)} a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$(1)$ $m(p,q)>0$ if $p≠q$ and $m(p,q)=0\iff p=q$:  obvious

$(2)$ $m(p,q)=m(q,p)$:   obvious

Now I thought that the triangle inequality need not hold with this definition, but I haven't been able to find a counter example in $\mathbb{R^2}$. So my question is does

$(3)$ $m(p,q)≤m(p,r)+m(r,q) $

necessarily hold with this definition? If so, how should I go about proving it, and if not is it possible to find a counterexample in $\mathbb{R^2}$? Or should I look elsewhere for counterexamples?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please be sure to check this guide of MathJax formatting so you can correctly format your future questions (or answers): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308972/is-this-function-a-metric/1308979#1308979